# ImportError: cannot import name ellipkm1

Tags: python, scipy

I was trying to import scipy.stats, however keep getting the error of 'ImportError: cannot import name ellipkm1'

Here's the complete track record of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 321, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 180, in <module>
    import scipy.special as special
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 603, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\basic.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import (ellipkm1, mathieu_a, mathieu_b, iv, jv, gamma, psi, zeta,
ImportError: cannot import name ellipkm1
```

So what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Thanks Anand for editing!

Comment: Do you have a file called `_ufuncs` or `ellipkm1` ?

Comment: I did find several files with _ufuncs in their names

Comment: Did you use conda to install scipy?

Comment: I didn't. Just directly download a package from this link and install: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/latest/download

Comment: btw the operating system is windows 7 (32bit)

Comment: Try using `pip install scipy`

Comment: It returns invalid syntax...

Comment: i am facing the same problem and scipy is already installed via conda.

Comment: You can try installing [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) and see if works better afterwards. Did it help?

Answer (score 2):

I had to upgrade:

```
pip install scipy --upgrade
```

to scipy==0.16.1 to make it work.
Note that I had uninstalled scipy from root and installed it in a virtualenv.

Also, If you want to use the same version of scipy, you can run:

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall scipy
```

I had scipy==0.15.1 and the command above fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with scipy installed through conda.
Running

```
conda upgrade scipy -f
```

fixed it for me. I used the `-f` flag since I already had scipy installed at the most recent version.