# Error while trying to update and use scipy module in Anaconda

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I am relatively new to Python and have been trying to get Anaconda updated to the latest version. Unfortunately, `scipy` wouldn't import at all. I have installed and uninstalled base Anaconda 7 times today, without any luck.

Here's `sys.version`

```
'3.6.6 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Here are the steps I followed:

**1. Update Anaconda**

I installed base anaconda from the website. Then, I logged in as Admin to Anaconda Navigator and opened Terminal for the `root` environment.

From there I launched `conda update --all`. This completed successfully.

After upgrading the installation, when I run the following command:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
norm(50,10).pdf(45)
```

I get an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ellipkm1'

**2. Research SO and Internet for this error:**

I followed [ImportError: cannot import name ellipkm1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692363/importerror-cannot-import-name-ellipkm1) thread and ensured that I have the latest MS C++ Redistributable and that there are no files with the name `ellipkm1`.

I also tried `conda upgrade scipy -f`, as suggested in above thread. This command ran without any errors.

Any thoughts on what is missing? I am a beginner so I am unsure what's going on here. I will be more than happy to provide any debug/log info needed here.

---

From [Is there a test suite for numpy / scipy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200727/is-there-a-test-suite-for-numpy-scipy) thread, I tried testing `scipy` module. `scipy` module failed entirely.

```
import scipy
scipy.test('full')
```

---

**Update:** It seems downgrading `scipy` to 1.0.1 (the next level) solves `ellipkm1` issue. I am still running all test cases above.

---

**Update:** It seems most of the test cases did pass. There seems to be an issue with `1.1.0`. I am not sure whether I am the only person who is having this issue.