# Test Anaconda build after updating packages

Tags: python, build, anaconda, updates

I use `conda update --all` to update my packages. Recently, I encountered an error with Anaconda build, posted at [Error while trying to update and use scipy module in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602576/error-while-trying-to-update-and-use-scipy-module-in-anaconda). It seems now the issue has been fixed. Is there any way, I can test all modules one by one by importing them and deleting them ? I am requesting this because I have noticed that if import doesn't work, I spend a lot of time figuring out the dependency and then the package that is causing this. For instance, a few minutes ago I found that PyCharm 2018.2.4 breaks with the latest version of `matplotlib` (3.0.0). Hence, it might be helpful to run some type of test script after running `conda update --all` to ensure that all packages are indeed working--i.e. importable.

I did some research on this topic and found three sources.

First, Anaconda offers `run_test.py` (Source: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/recipe.html). However, being new to the world of Python, I am unsure how to go about running a script in Anaconda terminal.

Second, I found: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/test-installation.html. However, this just tells me the version of the package. I am not interested in the version. I need to know whether all packages import properly.

Finally, I found out that there is a method to run test script for all packages at https://anaconda-installer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html. However, I am unsure how I can run `make` in Anaconda terminal. I used to use `make` long time ago when I worked on `gcc` on Unix environment. Being new to Python, I am unsure how to go about handling this.

I'd appreciate any thoughts or any test script that could help us verify two things:

a) whether all packages have been installed

b) packages are indeed importable; If the package import fails, the script should terminate with handsome error message highlighting the source (package) where import failed.

Comment: Anaconda installer has nothing to do with the Python Anaconda distribution, so that's a bit of a red herring. The `run_test.py` for a recipe is only done when building the package, so also not helpful. I'm not sure that what you want to do is (easily/automatically) possible, but if you want some assurances that all the software will work together, just use the `anaconda` package, which installs a bunch of common packages that Anaconda Inc. say work well together, and don't run `conda update --all`

Comment: Thanks darthbith. I did that for about a month, and as I progressed, I realized that I am missing out on many features and bug-fixes available in the latest version.

Comment: Then use new environments for each project where you only install the dependencies that you need for that project. That way you can run `conda update --all` and it won't have so many packages to update, and you have a better chance of not having errors.

Comment: @dartbith: Thanks again for your feedback. I think the issue is not about using virtual environment or standalone Anaconda, but about testing the distribution after updating the packages. In both cases, I would need a test script.